# Создание символической ссылки в PHP

Tags: php, exec

"Задача: понадобится phpmyadmin создаете ссылку на /usr/share/phpMyAdmin в корне сайта с любым именем и заходите"

```html
у меня не получается , проверила существование ссылки - обе ссылки существуют. 
//echo "is=".file_exists($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]');//возвращает 1
//echo "is=".file_exists('/usr/share/phpMyAdmin');
//возвращает 1
//die();
//exec('ln -s  /usr/share/phpMyAdmin '.$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]); // не работает , пустая страница вылезает
exec('ln -s  /usr/share/phpMyAdmin '.$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], $output);
var_dump($output); //возвращает пустой массив array(0) { }
```

как исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь [symlink()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.symlink.php), а не `exec()`:

> Возвращаемые значения
>
> Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае
>   возникновения ошибки.

Также, на будущее: хорошим тоном рекомендуется не просто проверять существование файла на диске через `file_exists()` -- а ещё и при помощи `is_dir` проверять, не является ли файл каталогом (с точки зрения ОС linux каталог -- это тоже файл) или симлинком при помощи `is_link`. Мне кажется, что и эти функции вам неизвестны.

Если симлинк не создаётся -- хорошо бы проверить, а есть ли у пользователя, под которым работает веб-сервер доступ на создание симлинка.

Comment: `echo is_link('/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/');
echo  is_link($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);` ничего не выводят. Делала ` echo symlink ('/usr/share/phpMyAdmin', $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);` не помогло

Comment: `shell_exec("cd /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/");` или `shell_exec("cd /home/bitrix/www/phpmyadmin/");`
`$output = shell_exec('ls -al');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"`; не помогло.  что-то выводят одинаковую структруру файлов, не похожую на структуру файлов phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

команда ln, если все прошло удачно, ничего кроме системного STDERR=0 не возвращает. Никакого текста.

Для получения системного кода ошибки надо запускать так

```
exec('command', $output, $error);
```

где в $output попадет вывод в поток stdout, а в $error - целочисленный код возврата команды

Для того, что бы в $output получить и stdout и stderr надо дополнить запускаемую команду таким образом

```
exec('command 2>&1', $output, $error);
```

Comment: exec('ln -s  /usr/share/phpMyAdmin '.$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], $output);
var_dump($output); //возвращает пустой массив array(0) { }- Это STDERR=0?

Comment: Приведите точный вывод var_dump в вопросе

Comment: вот вывод array(0) { }

Comment: @NNN в $output возвращается именно консольный вывод исполняемой команды. STDERR - это код возврата, ни в стандартный ни в ошибочный вывод он не попадает. Обновил ответ для понимания.